# Apache cache-control max-age cannot be overridden

Tags: flash, apache, apache2, streaming, cache-control

I'm trying to set cache-control attribute on Apache 2.2 so that the client connecting wont' cache anything. I have added various Header attributes in the httpd.conf file, however these attributes do not override the default max-age and expires header. These are the values I have in httpd.conf for Header attributes:

```
   Header set Expires "Thu, 01 Dec 2003 16:00:00 GMT"
   Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
```

The resulting headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2012 18:06:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) DAV/2
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 18:06:36 GMT, Thu, 01 Dec 2003 16:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 548113
Last-Modified: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 22:08:04 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/f4f
```

So the cache-control header is still sending "max-age=86400", and appending the rest of the attributes.  How can I completely override this value? I also tried to use the mod_expires module, this is the edit for httpd.conf that I made, however it didn't seem to do anything:

```
<IfModule mod_expires>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault 0
</IfModule>
```

So can anyone out there tell me how to completely override Apache's cache-control and expires headers for every request? We are running Apache 2.2 on Windows for flash media streaming server. I want to override evertything because the server sends many esoteric formats depending on the client connecting to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one here:

```
Header unset Expires
Header set Expires "Thu, 01 Dec 2003 16:00:00 GMT"
```

I read somewhere that it is bette to remove the old headers first. So the [`unset`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header) rule will do that.

If this not work try [mod expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html):

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType video/f4f "access minus 9 years"
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work, it just appended just like the result I posted above.  In theory if I unset and do not set a new value there should not have been any headers right?

Comment: @PaysonWelch try my update. Ah you use that already... maybe the problem is that you use both